Runnable jar file "A Java exception has occurred"
I recently got back into Java. Just installed Eclipse 2024-03 as well as 1.8.0_411. Coded a simple program that just opens a 500x500 pixels JFrame and closes when that frame is closed. Using JRE 17.
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new MyFrame();
        }
    }

    public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
        public MyFrame() {
            setTitle("Test");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(500, 500);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

I then exported it to a runnable jar file (right click on project, "Export", runnable jar file, extract libraries...).
Then when I tred to run the runnable jar file, a single window opened stating "A Java exception has occurred". The program runs like it's supposed to on Eclipse, but won't run at all after export.
Similar questions have been asked, but none of the answers seemed particularly clear to me. I'm not just trying to fix the issue, but also to understand what causes it.
I know how to code, but I'm way out of my depth with this issue.
Please help?
EDIT: After running the program from the command line, it returned the following message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zaromachian/redbox/main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)


What happens when you run the jar file from the command  line? This way, if any exceptions are thrown, you can see the full stack trace.

I don't know what command line you're talking about, much less how to do it.

What operating system are you using? Windows? If so, then you would use Window's File Manager to go to the directory holding the jar file, open a command window (usually by typing cmd in the file manager's address bar), and then run the jar as you would from any command line.

I just did that, and the same thing happened: a simple window stating "A Java Exception has occurred."

The window is named "Java Virtual Machine Launcher".

How did you run the jar file on the command line? What command did you use? And the command window showed no text of its own, no error message?

What do you mean by "1.8.0_411" and "JRE 17"? Are you using JDK 8 or JDK 17?

Nope, no error message. I typed "start .jar" (without the chevrons of course). No exception or error message of any kind in the command prompt.

I mean I checked the version of java that's installed on my computer, and it said "1.8.0_411".

Wait, you typed start? That's not how you run a jar file. Rather, it's more like java -jar my-app.jar or something similar.

Basically last time I opened Eclipse, I coded a game, exported it and had it run just fine. Today I did the same thing, having just updated everything, and now it doesn't work anymore. And I'm completely lost becausse I never had to manage versions, JREs or JDKs and whatnot before.

Alright, now it returns an error message. I'll post it in the question.

Perhaps we could get to the bottom of this with less venting and with more actionable information. Again, what happens when you run the jar file correctly using the java -jar ... command as per the Java tutorials?

OK, now we're getting somewhere. Please look at the duplicate as well as these similar questions and their answers. Time to update your JDK, SDK versions and your JAVA_HOME settings.

Fixed. Found the solution on one of those other answers. Thank you, and sorry about the venting.
